# Please show $|\sin(n+1)x| = |\sin(nx+x)|$

Tags: trigonometry

Pretty straightforward. I'm looking at a textbook for analysis, in chapter 1, I am not familiar with how

$|\sin(n+1)x| = |\sin(nx+x)|$

Could someone show me the proof or method here? I'm sure it's quite simple but I don't see it.

Comment: your notation is ambiguous.  It looks like your left hand side should be "$\sin((n+1)x)$".

Comment: Pretty straight forward identity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume that on the left-hand side, we actually have $|\sin[(n + 1)x]|$, in which case we need only distribute $x$ within the argument of $\sin$ to obtain the right-hand side of the equation.

$((n + 1)x) = (nx + x)$.

It's as simple as that.

Comment: I do not want to sound mean or anything, but don't you think this answer looks more like a comment?

Comment: @AtahualpaInca But it answers the question, that's all there is to it. It doesn't make sense to have a large answer on something this simple.

Comment: I asked the question to amWhy

Comment: @Atahualpa Before judging, please search the meta.mse site for discussions about the unfortunate growing number of "unanswered" questions, in part due to those who comment but do not answer.

Comment: why this eagerness to eat more when already eaten enough?

Comment: @AtahualpaInca I don't dine on questions, sorry about that. Answering questions, at least for me, is not a matter of "competing" or "hunting" or "consuming". It's about helping, at least for me. You're going to make yourself very unhappy, and quickly so, if you view this site as a "game" or competition.

Comment: If your objective is to help people, why don't you put this one line answer in the comment box?

Comment: Furthermore, if your objective is to help people, and(according to you) there is an unfortunate growing number of unanswered questions, why don't you try to solve this questions ?

Comment: @AtahualpaInca I am curious, what do you think should be placed as an answer to a question like this? amWhy's answer seems to be exactly answering the question -- the entire point of an answer.

Comment: @AtahualpaInca There have been numerous discussions about answering questions through comments; the purpose of comments are for clarification and short points, and should be considered ephemeral. In fact, it's discouraged to simply answer in a comment. Regardless, if you object to people giving short and brief answers to questions, then you ought to bring it up on meta, not here.

Comment: Click the add comment link under the question, it says: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: @AtahualpaInca Please keep meta discussions out of here and stop harassing users.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Is this typically how arguments for sine are written? I feel like the way you have written in in your answer makes much more sense, in fact, aren't the extra set of brackets necessary? Otherwise what I wrote in my question should be interpreted as (sin(n+1))*x, right?

Comment: @amWhy: Perfectly fine answer +1

Comment: The displayed identity alone, with the outer parentheses omitted on each side, would be a sufficient answer—and all the clearer for its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the spacing between words in written text, the spacing around binary mathematical operators (such as $+$ or $-$) and unary operators (e.g. $\sin$, $\exp$, etc.) is critical in determining the meaning.

As a general rule of mathematical typography, mathematical functions written as operators—that is, simply prefixed to the argument—are printed in roman type, followed by a thin space that precedes the argument. For example:$$\sin x+\sin y =2\sin\tfrac12(x+y)\sin\tfrac12(x-y),$$$$\ln xy=\ln x+\ln y,\qquad\quad$$$$\exp(x+y)=\exp x+\exp y.\qquad\qquad$$In the above examples, the typography makes the expressions completely unambiguous. Any additional parentheses would just add clutter, while the existing parentheses are needed.

In the particular case of your question, we have the simple algebraic identity$$(n+1)x=nx+x.$$When applying the sine function to this quantity, we need no further parentheses on the left-hand side; but parentheses must be introduced on the right-hand side because otherwise it would read as $$\sin nx+x,$$which is the sum of $\sin nx$ and $x$.